# Segmentation fault with pthread_create

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, mutex

I try to understand pthread and mutex in C. I want two write a program, that calculates the square of a given value and stores it in an array of given size. I want to create 4 pthreads that calculate each a value and then store them. So I expect the following result: [25] [25] ... [25], with x=5, a=10 (array size).
My code so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <error.h>

#define NTHREADS 4
static int k = 0;

struct thread_info{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    int x;
    int a[10];
};

void* fkt(void* arg){
    struct thread_info* tinfo = (struct thread_info*) arg;

    if(pthread_mutex_lock(&tinfo->lock)) perror("mutex_lock");

    printf("THREAD %d with argument %d\n", (int) tinfo->thread_id, tinfo->x);

    tinfo->a[k] = tinfo->x * tinfo->x;
    k++;

    if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&tinfo->lock)) perror("mutex_unlock");

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    struct thread_info* tinfo = (struct thread_info*) malloc(sizeof(struct thread_info));

    tinfo->x = 5;

    if(pthread_mutex_init(&tinfo->lock, NULL)) perror("mutex_init");

    for(int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++){
        if(pthread_create(&tinfo[i].thread_id, NULL, &fkt, &tinfo)) perror("pthread_create");
    }   
    for(int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++){
        if(pthread_join(tinfo[i].thread_id, NULL)) perror("pthread_join");
        printf("THREAD JOINED: %d\n", (int) tinfo->thread_id);
    }   
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("[%d]\t", tinfo->a[i]);
    }   
    printf("\n");

    if(pthread_mutex_destroy(&tinfo->lock)) perror("mutex_destroy");

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I get a segmentation fault and I dont see why. Valgrind says "Invalid write of size 4" What does that statement mean?

EDIT: I removed the NULL from the declaration of tinfo in the main function. Still getting a segmentation fault with valgrind. Executing the binary seems to run infinitely.

Comment: You're *never allocating any memory* for `tinfo`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may also be passing a pointer to your thread's target function argument incorrectly when you call `pthread_create`. Since the variable `tinfo` is `malloc`'d in your `main` function, it is already a pointer. However, when you pass in your target function's argument to `pthread_create`, you pass in `&tinfo`, which effectively has the type `struct thread_info **`. That is, it isn't a pointer to a `struct thread_info` but rather a pointer that can be dereferenced once to get a pointer to a `struct thread_info`. This causes problems since `fkt`treats this pointer as a `struct thread_info *`, which is incorrect. I'd bet that replacing `&tinfo` with just `tinfo` in your call to `pthread_create` would help solve the issue.

Comment: and it did. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad it worked out!

Comment: The program is *still* buggy, Valgrind should be screaming at you with heap overflow.

Answer (score 2):

> Unfortunately I get a segmentation fault and I dont see why.

It's not hard to see why: these two lines at the start of the program guarantee it:

```
struct thread_info* tinfo = NULL;
tinfo->x = 5;
```

The second line attempts to write to (dereference) a `NULL` pointer created on the first line.

You should learn to use a debugger, so you don't get stumped by such trivial bugs.

(There probably are other bugs in your program, I didn't look.)

**Update:**

Now you've corrected the first problem, but introduced a new one: this line allocates space for *one* `thread_info`:

```
struct thread_info* tinfo =
  (struct thread_info*) malloc(sizeof(struct thread_info));
```

But this line overflows that buffer for all values of `i` above `0`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NTHREADS; i++){
    if(pthread_create(&tinfo[i].thread_id, ...
```

Comment: I've updated the answer: you *really* should learn to use a debugger.